# PHP Class Instance Set and Used Before Hook Called

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have a class that has the following construct:

```
    public function __construct() {

        self::$instance = $this;

        $this->args['opt_name'] = "dovydastest";

        /** When the rest of WP has loaded, kick-start the rest of the class */
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }

    function init() {
        do_action( 'simple_options_register' );
```

Inside the init() function I have a do_action that changes the $this->args variable. The problem is on admin_init and such that init() is fired AFTER what I need.

Is there any way around it or do I need to add a custom filter inside the construct (which gets re-called repeatedly and I had hoped not to use).

Comment: Please don't use the reference operator (`&`) for PHP objects. They are already implicitly passed by reference

Comment: Will do. Changed my code to above. Do you have a potential solution otherwise or must I declare this in the construct for it to truly pass?

Comment: I have no idea. Wordpress and its action hooks confuse and anger me